# Installing new version of Exhange (2013) on a new server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

I have an Exchange 2010 server running.

Some nights ago I tried to install Exchange 2013 on a new server, the installation stopped because the setup detected an instance of Exchange 2010 not running Service Pack 1 (my existing server).

I wanted to install 2013 separate, get the service up and running and move/upgrade the database at a convenient moment, apparently the setup can do some magic for me ?

I could use some tips on best practice and the required installation steps for the scenario:

- Exchange 2010 without SP1 is running on Server 2008
- I have a new server 2012 on the same domain where I want to install Exchange 2013
- When the new Exchange is up and running I need to remove all Exchange related stuff from the Server 2008, that computer is also a DC so I cannot simply discard it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have two versions of Exchange running in the same forest which means that you are essentially configuring Exchange for co-existence, even if the servers will only be co-existing for as long as it takes to set up the new server, move mailboxes, and remove the old one.

In order to do this with Exchange 2010 and Exchange 2013, there are some requirements:

- Exchange 2010 must be patched to **SP3**
- Exchange 2013 must be patched to CU1 (there should be an Exchange 2013 installer available from Microsoft with this 'baked in')

This is discussed by Microsoft in their [Exchange Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/02/12/released-exchange-server-2010-sp3.aspx):

> Coexistence with Exchange 2013:Customers who want to introduce Exchange Server 2013 into their existing Exchange 2010 infrastructure will need the coexistence changes shipping in SP3.
>
> NOTE: Exchange 2010 SP3 allows Exchange 2010 servers to coexist with Exchange 2013 CU1, which is also scheduled to be released in Q1 2013. Customers can test and validate this update in a representative lab environment prior to rolling out in their production environments as an important coexistence preparatory step before introducing Exchange Server 2013 CU1.

There's no way around this need to patch the servers, I'm afraid.

As for removing Exchange 2010, that should be a fairly simple matter of un-installing Exchange on the server. Before doing that there may be some stuff you need to do to tidy up your Exchange org - the precise details of what you will need to do depend on your exact Exchange configuration and are something you'll have to get from applying Microsoft's documentation to your specific scenario.

Comment: The uninstall of Exchange 2010 will also fail if you have anything outstanding that still needs to be moved off of the server, and will tell you exactly what you forgot.

Comment: Good point @JeremyLyons - the newer versions of Exchange are much less likely to leave you high and dry than the old ones.